# how to use echo to echo div if condition within that div is met

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I have a simple php script that I am using to display social icons if user has provided their social network username in the fields of their user account in wordpress.

Problem is that all of the network icons are being displayed even if the networks username was not provided.

I clearly understand the reason why it is happening since all of the divs are wrapped in the same echo output, but cannot really figure out how to use isset within that echo to output if condition of each div is met individually.

I hope that my explanation of the problem is not too confusing

Here is example of my script

```
    echo '
<div class="author_networks">
<div class="gplus"><a class="soc_btn gplus_img" href="https://plus.google.com/'. get_the_author_meta('google_plus', $authorID) .'" rel="me" target="_blank"></a></div>
<div class="facebook"><a class="soc_btn facebook_img" href="http://www.facebook.com/'. get_the_author_meta('facebook', $authorID) .'" target="_blank"></a></div>
<div class="twitter"><a class="soc_btn twitter_img" href="http://twitter.com/'. get_the_author_meta('twitter', $authorID) .'" target="_blank"></a></div>
<div class="linkedin"><a class="soc_btn linkedin_img" href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/'. get_the_author_meta('linkedin', $authorID) .'" target="_blank"></a></div>
</div>
</div>'
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sime `IF` statement will work:

```
<?
echo '<div class="author_networks">';
if ($condition == 'gplus') {
    echo '<div class="gplus"><a class="soc_btn gplus_img" href="https://plus.google.com/' . get_the_author_meta('google_plus', $authorID) . '" rel="me" target="_blank"></a></div>';
} elseif ($condition == 'facebook') {
    echo '<div class="facebook"><a class="soc_btn facebook_img" href="http://www.facebook.com/' . get_the_author_meta('facebook', $authorID) . '" target="_blank"></a></div>';
} elseif ($condition == 'twitter') {
    echo '<div class="twitter"><a class="soc_btn twitter_img" href="http://twitter.com/' . get_the_author_meta('twitter', $authorID) . '" target="_blank"></a></div>';
} elseif ($condition == 'linkedin') {
    echo '<div class="linkedin"><a class="soc_btn linkedin_img" href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/' . get_the_author_meta('linkedin', $authorID) . '" target="_blank"></a></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: This is the way I have just used which helped me to solve the problem

Comment: This way only provides one social icon, even if there are more

Comment: actually I have used your method, but slightly modified it with use of separate echo for each div and it works just fine. I have not used the {} around the echo, is it OK not to use them?

Answer (score 1):

Use separate echo calls for each `<div>`:

```
echo '<div class="author_networks">';
if(isset(get_the_author_meta('google_plus', $authorID))) {
 echo '<div class="gplus">...</div>';
}
if(isset(get_the_author_meta('facebook', $authorID))) {
 echo '<div class="facebook">...</div>';
}
// and so on
echo '</div>';
```

Assuming that `get_the_author_meta()` returns `null` when there is no author data available. If not, you need to use another method to check if the data is available.

Comment: any idea why? I've realised that one bracket was actually missing, but even after correcting it, it still is giving me 500

Comment: It was missing 2, one in each `if`-statement. As far as I can see my updated code snippet does not contain any errors (anymore), so I guess there is something wrong in your updated code? If you cannot find it, you should open a new question, with details about the error and to provide the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use separate `echo` per each icon

Answer (score 0):

You need to break it in separate parts, and you should remove the echo and replace it with html outside php. Like this:

```
?><div class="author_networks"><?php
if (/*google plus check*/) { ?><div class="gplus"><a class="soc_btn gplus_img" href="https://plus.google.com/<?php echo get_the_author_meta('google_plus', $authorID); ?>" rel="me" target="_blank"></a></div>
```

Do this for all 4-5 entries, and you're done.